# override template in to ez publish 5, tpl file to twig

Tags: ezpublish

I need your help!
I use ez publish 5 and need override template  for forgotpasswordmail.tpl
can anyone help? 
some examples code  would be great for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a legacy extension created for your code and a legacy design active, the best practice would be to place the new template in your legacy extension with the same directory structure as the original one.

The original file is placed in `ezpublish_legacy/design/standard/templates/user/forgotpasswordmail.tpl`, so you need to place yours in `ezpublish_legacy/extension/my_extension/design/my_design/templates/user/forgotpasswordmail.tpl`

After clearing the legacy caches, eZ Publish 5 will pick up the new file automatically.

If you do not have the design yet, to activate it, first you need to create a `design.ini.append.php` file in `my_extension/settings` folder with the following content:

```
<?php /* #?ini charset="utf-8"?

[ExtensionSettings]
DesignExtensions[]=my_extension
*/ ?>
```

This makes the extension a "design extension", meaning eZ Publish will look into the extension when searching for designs.

Then you need to set your siteaccess to use the new design in `ezpublish_legacy/settings/siteaccess/YOUR_SITEACCESS/site.ini.append.php`
 and clear the caches:

```
[DesignSettings]
SiteDesign=my_design
```

Comment: how to find what is my extention name ? i understand what  i must do but i do not understand how to find right extention folder name , after ezpublish_legacy/extension/ i do not know  what to do

Comment: I have created ezpublish_legacy/extension/my_extension/design/my_design/templates/user/forgotpasswordmail.tpl , and i switched on extension , but not working , what can i do?

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional instructions on how to add the design

Comment: Thank you very much, i`ll try now , hope it`s work for me.

Comment: Strange but it not working for me , i make files and folders step by step your example  and i had already override and siteaccess folders and  files (design.ini.append.php,site.ini.append.php) but not working and  when i send mail   it use  old template instead new one :(

it is screen of my extention folder tree, have a look it maybe i`m doing something wrong
(img url: https://ibb.co/jXdg2Q)

Comment: It  is working my kind friend, you real help me !!!  the problem was in my design name, i change my_design to standard and everything is working now !!